# Rails "unknown command" ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, argument-error

I am working on the Michael Hartl rails tutorial. When running my tests, I get the following Error:

```
Error:
UserTest#test_associated_microposts_should_be_destroyed:
ArgumentError: unknown command 'a'
test/models/user_test.rb:73:in 'test'
test/models/user_test.rb:73: in 'block in <class:UserTest>'
```

"test/models/user_test.rb" is as follows:

```
test "associated microposts should be destroyed" do
@user.save
@user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem ipsum")
assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
@user.destroy
end
```

The test is straightforward and only aims at testing the following line in my model (user.rb)

```
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

If I comment this sentence as follows:

```
has_many :microposts#, dependent: :destroy
```

I, as expected, get

```
Failure: [...] "Micropost.count" didn't change by -1. Expected:38 Actual 39.
```

If I uncomment the "dependent: :destroy" statement, I get this "unknown command" error. Could anyone give some guidance on how this error is most likely generated, what is a "command" in the context of rails (excluding the rails console) and where to look first to try to solve it (Models? Controllers?). Thanks.

Comment: Never gotten into tests, but shouldn't there be underscores in the test name? To make it `"associated_microposts_should_be_destroyed"`?

Comment: The model,db, and the test itself would be where I would look first since thats what you are testing. Make sure theres an association between users and microposts and that you ran rake db:migrate

Comment: Can you post the test file in its entirety ? (Remove as much of it as you can while still preserving the error)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your assert_difference call.

```
assert_difference 'Micropost.count" ...
```

Note the beginning single quotation mark and the ending double quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. This is is just a typo when writing the question though. The error is not related to this oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-crunched my code and noticed by deleting each test that even though only one test was reported in the failure log, I could get rid of the failure by removing either one of two different tests separately that were at the bottom of my test file as follows:

```
test "associated microposts should be destroyed" do
@user.save
@user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem ipsum")
assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
  @user.destroy
end

test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
   assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
  end
end
.
.
```

The issue was that one of the "end" was misplaced. The file should have been:

```
test "associated microposts should be destroyed" do
@user.save
@user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem ipsum")
assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
  @user.destroy
end
end
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
   assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
end
```

I would still be interested in understanding why the failure log retrieved "unknown command 'a'" to improve my understanding of rails testing environment down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now and there is this;

At the top of `micropost_test.rb` there is this setup

```
//first post creation for @user
def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    # This code is not idiomatically correct.
    @micropost = @user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum")
end

//second post creation in test for @user
test "associated microposts should be destroyed" do
    @user.save
    @user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem ipsum")
    assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
    @user.destroy
end
```

There a post is already created, so when user is saved with another post in test, then that user is deleted actually 2 posts with him are gone. So what we expect should be -2 difference.